# How to get mac address of your computer in PHP?

Tags: php

How to get mac address of your computer in PHP?

Comment: Your computer you mean the host? or the client? to get host MAC simply shell_exec("ifconfig") and extract MAC from the result string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PHP itself does not offer a function to find out. You need to invoke the plattform-specific tool to get the information, then extract it:

```
$text = `ifconfig`;
preg_match('/([0-9a-f]{2}:){5}\w\w/i', $text, $mac);
$mac = $mac[0];
```

On Windows you might be able to use `ipconfig` with some option.